How to Prevent sandbox from sending Workflow emails to "Additional Emails" in Email Alerts using Metadata API in Apex?
I want to prevent sandbox environments from sending Workflow emails to the "Additional Emails" specified in Email Alerts using the Metadata API in Apex.
I tried using the Tooling API, but it only allows metadata retrieval and doesn’t support updates. After researching, I found that the Metadata API might help achieve this. However, I haven’t been able to find a clear solution for this use case.
I have created below Apex class to retrieve and update CCEmail using Metadata API with the help of MetadataService class. Please have a look in the code here:
public class UpdateCCEmail {


    public void updateEmailAlertCC(String emailAlertFullName, List<String> newCcEmails) {

        // Step 1: Create MetadataService instance
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();

        // Use Named Credential directly; this assumes you have 'MetadataAPI' defined correctly.
        service.endpoint_x = 'callout:MetaNameCred/services/Soap/m/58.0'; // Use the appropriate version

        // Step 2: Prepare the session header (if necessary)
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        // Step 3: Read the existing EmailAlert metadata
        MetadataService.IReadResult readResult = service.readMetadata('WorkflowAlert ', new String[] {
            emailAlertFullName
        });

        if (readResult == null || readResult.getRecords().size() == 0) {
            System.debug('No records found for the specified Email Alert: ' + emailAlertFullName);
            return;
        }

        // Step 4: Cast the metadata to EmailAlert type
        MetadataService.WorkflowAlert emailAlert = (MetadataService.WorkflowAlert) readResult.getRecords()[0];

        // Step 5: Update the CC Emails
        emailAlert.ccEmails = newCcEmails;

        // Step 6: Prepare the update request as Metadata
        MetadataService.Metadata[] updateRequest = new MetadataService.Metadata[] {
            emailAlert
        };

        // Step 7: Perform the update call with the correct parameter
        MetadataService.SaveResult[] saveResults = service.updateMetadata(updateRequest);

        // Step 8: Check for success
        for (MetadataService.SaveResult saveResult : saveResults) {
            if (saveResult.success) {
                System.debug('Email Alert updated successfully: ' + emailAlertFullName);
            }
            else {
                System.debug('Failed to update Email Alert: ' + saveResult.errors[0].message);
            }
        }
    }
}

I came across similar issues posted by others:
How to prevent emails to 'Aditional Email' on email alerts
Preventing sandbox from sending Workflow emails to "Additional Emails"
However, none of these discussions provide a concrete solution.
Could anyone suggest how to programmatically mask, remove, or disable these alerts in a sandbox?

This question is similar to: Preventing sandbox from sending Workflow emails to "Additional Emails". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

^^^ Merely 11+ year old answer is still correct. The more things change, the more they stay the same.

You need to describe the specific error or issue with your class.  Please [edit] your post to include those details.

@identigral, In the suggested solution, they advised changing the deliverability setting to "System Email Only." However, this is not the appropriate fix for my requirement. I need a more generic solution, such as an Apex code script that interacts with the sandbox API to update each Workflow Alert, specifically modifying the value in the "Additional Emails" field, e.g., changing xyz@gmail.com to xyz@gmail.com.invalid.

@DavidCheng, that code is not working at all. I need a generic solution like Apex code script that interacts with the sandbox API to update each Workflow Alert.

You need to describe "not working at all".  Are you getting a specific error?  What do you see in your debug log?  Please edit your post to include the details.

@DavidCheng, I am getting below error while executing the code in Developer console:
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: type is not a valid metadata type for reading faultcode=sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION faultactor=

Are you using the opensource MetadataService?  Have you checked the issues in that repository and done any other research?

@DavidCheng, After conducting research, I've concluded that the Metadata Service only supports retrieving metadata and does not allow updates. Could you have alternative approaches for this requirement?

You will have to make callouts to the Metadata API, see documentation for one possibility.
